# Chrome command-line arguments do not work on Windows 10

Tags: google-chrome, command-line

I am attempting to send command-line arguments to Chrome in order to disable CORS support and allow local file access.  For some reason it works under Mac OS X and not Windows.  I am attempting the following commands:

```
C:\>cd "Program Files (x86)"\google\chrome\application
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application>chrome --args --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security
```

I am also attempting the same command without the --args flag.

Answer (score 1):

I had to use:
    .\chrome.exe

Windows was looking in my system PATH for the binary and this messed up the parameter passing.

Comment: Didn't work. Where exactly did you change it to `.\chrome.exe`? It won't even let me set it that way.

Comment: on the second line, where it says 'chrome --args', I made it '.\chrome.exe --args'.  You must be in Chrome's directory to do this.